# LocalScroll to two divs with a single link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrollto

I'm trying to have a single link scroll to two different points within two different overflowed divs.

[Hereis a slightly working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tBxCj/)  that maybe more clearly explains what I'm trying to do.

**HTML**

```
<div id="small-box-links">

    <a href="#small-box1">Link to small-box #1 and #5</a>
    <a href="#small-box2">Link to small-box #2 and #4</a>
    <a href="#small-box3">Link to small-box #3 and #6</a>

</div>

<div id="small-box-container">
    <div id="small-box1" class="small-box">Small-Box #1</div>
    <div id="small-box2" class="small-box">Small-Box #2</div>
    <div id="small-box3" class="small-box">Small-Box #3</div>
</div>


<div id="small-box-container2">
    <div id="small-box4" class="small-box">Small-Box #4</div>
    <div id="small-box5" class="small-box">Small-Box #5</div>
    <div id="small-box6" class="small-box">Small-Box #6</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {

        // Scroll the content inside the #scroll-container div
        $('#small-box-links').localScroll({
           target:'#small-box-container'
        });

        $('#small-box-links').localScroll({
           target:'#small-box-container2'
        });


    });
```

**CSS**

```
#small-box-container {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;

        overflow: scroll;
    }

        #small-box-container2 {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;

        overflow: scroll;
    }

    .small-box {

        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;

        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0 0 50px 0;
    }

    #small-box1 {
        background: blue;
    }

    #small-box2 {
        background: red;
    }

    #small-box3 {
        background: green;
    }

    #small-box4 {
        background: orange;
    }

    #small-box5 {
        background: purple;
    }

    #small-box6 {
        background: yellow;
    }
```

Sorry in advance if this question has been asked, my searching has yielded no results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple logic
[Your solution is here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dego247/yE3r3/6/).
follow the link to get the full working code.

here is usage and best way to accomplish your aim in respect to your question:

```
$(function() {
    //========= Funct to Scroll box #1 n #4         
    $('a#box1').on('click', function() {
        $('#small-box1').ScrollTo();
        $('#small-box4').ScrollTo();
    });
    //========= Funct to Scroll box #2 n #5         
    $('a#box2').on('click', function() {
        $('#small-box2').ScrollTo();
        $('#small-box5').ScrollTo();
    });    
    //========= Funct to Scroll box #3 n #6         
    $('a#box3').on('click', function() {
        $('#small-box3').ScrollTo();
        $('#small-box6').ScrollTo();
    });
});
```